# Storing and processing range values in an array

Tags: vba, excel

While storing range values as a variant and looping through them i'm having trouble actually changing the value of, for example,

```
valsf(i, h) = (valsf(i - 1, h) + valsf(i + 1, h)) / 2
```

It will only change when I make it

```
Cells(i, h) = (valsf(i - 1, h) + valsf(i + 1, h)) / 2
```

Why is this?

Comment: I'd guess that you forgot to write the array back to the range at the end.

Comment: oh, okay, thanks. Would i need to write the array within each `if` and `end if`?

Comment: Yaou can write the array in one go to the range after the calculaton been completed.. like `range("XX:XX") = valsf`.